# insert multiple row into table using select however table has primery key in oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

I am facing issue while inserting multiple row in one go into table because column id has primary key and its created based on sequence.

for ex:

```
create table test (
  iD number primary key,
  name varchar2(10)
);


insert into test values (123, 'xxx');
insert into test values (124, 'yyy');
insert into test values (125, 'xxx');
insert into test values (126, 'xxx');
```

The following statement creates a constraint violoation error:

```
insert into test
(
   select (SELECT MAX (id) + 1 FROM  test) as id,
   name from test
  where name='xxx'
 );
```

This query should insert 3 rows in table test (having name=xxx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're saying that your query inserts rows with primary key ID based on a sequence. Yet, in your insert/select there is `select (SELECT MAX (id) + 1 FROM test) as id`, which clearly is **not** *based on sequence*. It may be the case that you are not using the term "sequence" in the usual, Oracle way.

Anyway, there are two options for you ...

1. [Create a sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6017.htm#SQLRF01314), e.g. `seq_test_id` with the starting value of `select max(id) from test` and use it (i.e. `seq_test_id.nextval`) in your query instead of the `select max(id)+1 from test`.
2. Fix the actual subselect to `nvl((select max(id) from test),0)+rownum` instead of `(select max(id)+1 from test)`.

**Please note**, however, that the option 2 (as well as your original solution) **will** cause you huge troubles whenever your code runs in multiple concurrent database sessions. So, option 1 is strongly recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
insert into test (
   select (SELECT MAX (id) FROM  test) + rownum as id,
   name from test
  where name='xxx'
 );
```

as a workaround.

Of course, you should be using [sequences](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views002.htm#ADMIN11792) for integer-primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert an ID/Primary Key value generated by a sequence you should use the sequence instead of selecting the max(ID)+1.

Usually this is done using a trigger on your table wich is executed for each row. See sample below:

```
CREATE TABLE "MY_TABLE" 
(   
  "MY_ID" NUMBER(10,0) CONSTRAINT PK_MY_TABLE PRIMARY KEY , 
  "MY_COLUMN" VARCHAR2(100)
);
/ 
CREATE SEQUENCE  "S_MY_TABLE" 
MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999
INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10 NOCACHE  ORDER  NOCYCLE  NOPARTITION ;
/
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "T_MY_TABLE" 
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON
  MY_TABLE
  REFERENCING OLD AS OLDEST NEW AS NEWEST
  FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEWEST.MY_ID IS NULL)
DECLARE
   IDNOW NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT  S_MY_TABLE.NEXTVAL INTO IDNOW FROM DUAL;
    :NEWEST.MY_ID := IDNOW;
  END;

/
ALTER TRIGGER "T_MY_TABLE" ENABLE;
/
insert into MY_TABLE (MY_COLUMN) values ('DATA1');
insert into MY_TABLE (MY_COLUMN) values ('DATA2');
insert into MY_TABLE (MY_ID, MY_COLUMN) values (S_MY_TABLE.NEXTVAL, 'DATA3');
insert into MY_TABLE (MY_ID, MY_COLUMN) values (S_MY_TABLE.NEXTVAL, 'DATA4');
insert into MY_TABLE (MY_COLUMN) values ('DATA5');
/
select * from MY_TABLE;
```

Comment: Jakob, trigger-based sequence generation has all the performance-related dangers of heavy context switching. For each row, it does two unnecessary switches, while in fact no switches are needed. I don't recommend doing this. It's always better to use sequences directly in inserts. Laziness of a developer is not an excuse.

Comment: We used this method when we ported a legacy application from SQL-Server (with IDENTITY columns) to Oracle. In our current environment the sequences are used directly.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for explaining. I'd like to advise on using the `when` clause for the triggers to avoid running their code when the `id` gets filled already in the calling SQL context. Not much of an improvement, but does some relief for the DB when the developers are not lazy. :-)

Comment: Thanx for your advice, I edited the sample code as you suggested